# Power set of the complement vs. complement of the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I can't figure out the way to proof this Power set of the complement vs. complement of the power set question. I tried proofing it using contrapositive but I couldn't get it.
Let A and B be subsets of set U:

Prove that $P(B_U^c) \setminus \{\emptyset\} \subseteq P(B)^c_{P(U)}$

Thanks for any hints or help.

Comment: Is $A$ really necessary here?

Comment: Use the definitions of A) power set, B) complement. Everything will fall into place.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X \in \mathcal{P}(B^c) \setminus \emptyset$. We're done if we can show that $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)^c$.

We have that $X \not = \emptyset$, and $(\forall x \in X)(x \not \in B)$.

Note that $\mathcal{P}(B)^c$ is precisely the set of $Y$ such that $(Y \subseteq U)$ and $(\exists y \in Y)(y \not \in B)$.

$X$ certainly satisfies this, hence $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)^c$.